# USB device working after driver uninstalled

Tags: usb, mouse

On a Windows 10 PC, there are 6 USB ports, 4 on the back of the case attached to the motherboard and 2 on the front which are attached via PCI. The computer is a HP Pavillion s3600a with no aftermarket modifications.

USB devices plugged into any of the ports are not responding at all when the computer initially boots. However, when a USB device is plugged into one of the ports on the back of the PC and the [PCI to USB controller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa939393(v=winembedded.5).aspx) driver is uninstalled via device manager, the device *sometimes* begins functioning correctly.

The device will continue functioning correctly until the computer is restarted/powered off. On next boot the device will not appear in device manager.

The drivers loaded are all standard Microsoft drivers, and there are no alternate drivers available from the HP website for the motherboard or any USB devices.

---

I disabled the "PCI to USB driver Host Controller" via device manager entirely (rather than just uninstalling it). Devices plugged into one of the ports on the back of the case are now functioning correctly, but neither of the two ports on the front of the case are working.

Comment: There isn't much to say about them. The computer is a HP Pavillion 3600a with no aftermarket modifications (I'm attempting to fix the computer for a friend), the hubs correspond to the 4 ports on the back and 2 on the front respectively.

Comment: There is no such thing as "PCI to USB hub", nor "OpenHCD hub" There are EHCI (USB 2.0) host controllers on PCI bus, and OpenHCD is who knows what. Please specify at least the chips, or post pictures of the devices. You are likely have wrong drivers.

Comment: You're right. I was describing the drivers loaded for the controllers, not the hub, which is just a "standard USB hub". They seem to be the standard microsoft drivers

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa939393(v=winembedded.5).aspx

Comment: ...loaded, and there are no relevant drivers on the HP support page, so I don't think it's a case of incorrect drivers.

By disabling the "EHCI host controller on PCI bus" completely , I've gotten the ports on the back of the case (OpenHCD ones attached to motherboard) all working reliably, so problem fixed I guess. The ports on the front of the case are dead, but that's not a problem for my friend.

Comment: If the system mentions "OpenHCD", it means that this computer has AMD processor/chipset. In old days USB1.1 was not unified, and some host USB did have Open hardware controller to run the FS portion of USB called OHCI. You definitely have a driver problem. I am not sure if this hardware is supported under Win10. Try to follow this: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03327635

Comment: W10 has several problems with USB devices. Try updating the drivers for the devices via Device Manager (let windows search for drivers).